# To find the Null Space of a matrix which is inside the module

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, scoping

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Delete All Output;
L = 1;
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
A = 0.1^2;
kb = (Y*Iyy)/L^3;
mb = 7850*A*L;
w1[x_, b_] := a1*Sin[b*x] + a2*Cos[b*x] + a3*Sinh[b*x] + a4*Cosh[b*x];
w2[x_, b_, z_] := 
  b1*Sin[b*(x - z)] + b2*Cos[b*(x - z)] + b3*Sinh[b*(x - z)] + 
   b4*Cosh[b*(x - z)];
e1 = w1[0, b];
e2 = D[w1[x, b], {x, 2}] /. x -> 0;
e3 = w2[1, b, z];
e4 = D[w2[x, b, z], {x, 2}] /. x -> 1;
e5 = w1[z, b] - w2[z, b, z];
e6 = (D[w1[x, b], {x, 1}] /. x -> z) - (D[w2[x, b, z], {x, 1}] /. 
     x -> z);
e7 = (D[w1[x, b], {x, 2}] /. x -> z) - (D[w2[x, b, z], {x, 2}] /. 
     x -> z);
e8 = (D[w1[x, b], {x, 3}] /. x -> z) - (D[w2[x, b, z], {x, 3}] /. 
     x -> z) - (k*w2[z, b, z]);
R = FullSimplify[
   Normal@CoefficientArrays[{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8}, {a1, a2,
        a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4}][[2]]];
s1 = FullSimplify[Det[R]]
```

The aim of this program is to `Find` the unknown `Coefficients` in the `Function` `w1` and `w2`. For that, I have to find the `Root` of the equation `s1`. Again I have to substitute this `Root` in `Matrix` `R` and solve for the `NullSpace` of `Matrix R`. I want to do all this activity inside  `Module` but could not able to carry out properly. It would be helpful if you direct me to some documentation about **how to use `Module`**.
And also which is  best `Function` (`NSolve , FindRoots,Reduce or FindInstances`)to find root of an equation ,

Comment: I see that both `s1` and `R` depend on`b` and `z`. Do you want to solve for `b` as a function of `z` by setting `s1` to zero? Or am I not getting your point?

Comment: both s1 and  R depends on  `k`  `b` and `z`  I will substitute some positive values for `k`  and any positive value between 0.1 to 0.9 for `z`.